# What does a `</div>` before doctype mean?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have just seen a webpage whose source code begins with

```
</div>
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="es" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="es" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="es" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="es" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="es" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
...
```

I have seen those IE comments before, in order to fix IE bugs. But what does it mean that `</div>`??

Is it a hack or something?

Comment: It means the document is mal-formed.

Comment: It is some accidental output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s invalid HTML, nothing more (and was likely an error on the author’s part). Putting this minimal example

```
</div>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

through the [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) yields the following errors:

> Line 1, Column 6: End tag seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected `<!DOCTYPE html>`.
>   Line 1, Column 6: Stray end tag div.
>   Line 2, Column 15: Stray doctype.

The conditional comments don’t have anything to do with it.

Comment: I already knew it's invalid, but I have seen people recommending invalid hacks. So I was wondering if it does something special.

Comment: @Oriol That’s why I say “nothing more”. It’s not any sort of hack, it’s just plain invalid.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing valid about it and is most likely a typo or an include file server-side with accidental output.

It's not black magic or a hack going on, but [is] just a malformed document.